# Close all Internet Explorer instances from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Can I close or kill **all** running Internet Explorer instances on Windows XP SP3 from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
C:\>taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
```

you can make a bat file killie.bat with that line in it. or just run that command above.

Comment: `taskkill /f /t /im iexplore.exe` is the one I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Great.  Regarding the /t,  what child processes are you finding iexplore.exe starts?

Comment: any pop-up windows

Comment: `SUCCESS: The process with PID 3748 child of PID 3672 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2540 child of PID 3672 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3920 child of PID 3672 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3672 child of PID 1496 has been terminated.`

Comment: @Radek as without /t will kill all instances of iexplore.exe and that didn't quite do it until you did it with /t, then i'm curious what kind of filenames do such child processes have? i'm interested what processes iexplore.exe spawns when a popup appears. any example?